# Why is this program for converting cartesian coordinates to Polar coordinates is not giving correct omega value?

Tags: c, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, iota

This is my program in C:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<math.h>
  int main()
  {   int x, y;
    printf("Enter the cartesian coordinates to be converted into respective polar coordinates");
    scanf(" %d %d", &x, &y );
    float r = sqrt(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2));
    float omega = atan(y/x);
    printf("The required polar coordinates are: (%f, %f)", r, omega);
    return 0;
}
```

Following input is made:

```
5 12
```

And I get:

```
The required polar coordinates are: (13.000000, 1.107149)
```

I think the output is only half correct.

I expected, if unit is radian, the output must be:

```
The required polar coordinates are: (13.000000, 0.3944444)
```

But the output comes out to be:

```
The required polar coordinates are: (13.000000, 1.107149)
```

Comment: `sqrt(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2))` Nobody ever remembers [`hypot()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot). Or [`atan2()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2)...

Comment: What is `12/5` in C?

Comment: Anyways, why do you think it should be 0.3944444 radians?

Comment: `atan((float)y/x);` will avoid the integer division issue and give (13.000000, 1.176005) as a result. Your expectations about the correct result may be incorrect.

Comment: If you reverse the coordinates to 12, 5 you will get what you expected `(13,0.394791119699762)`